# lock() on the same object I'm trying to exclusively access or use separate locking object?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

```
private class MyClass
{
    private static MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    private void ModifyObject()
    {
        lock(myObject)
        {
            myObject.UnsafeMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it alright to lock on `myObject` or must I declare another dedicated locking object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine, any object is good enough to act as a place to store the state of the lock.

It is a strong Red Flag in any code review however, hinting that the programmer is thinking about locks the wrong way.  There is no such thing as "locking an object to make it thread-safe" in .NET.  That notion does exist, the subject of much academic research, called STM or Software Transactional Memory.  But there's not a shred of support for that in the .NET framework.

You use a lock to *block code*.  Dangerous code that can be executed by more than one thread and reads or writes a variable.  Very often in more than one place, code that exists in *specific* places in your source code file.  You use a lock to ensure that only *one* thread can execute the code in these specific places at the same time.  The lock state is therefore associated with *sections of code*, not an object.  And should therefore require a dedicated object to store the lock state for those specific sections.  You show that you know what you are doing by having such a dedicated object, instead of just picking one that you've got laying around.  Also strongly self-documenting, making it much easier to see where a lock is taking place since you only have to search for the  name of the locking variable.

Comment: This doesn't make alot of sense. Generally, when you want a lock it's not because you want only one thread running that block of code, it's that you don't want some object accessed by multiple threads from any code anywhere.

Comment: Another victim of "I can lock an object and nobody else can get to it."

Comment: That's kind of like saying it's useless to mark variables private because they're still accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to `lock` on the object you want to synchronize access to, as long as you can be sure that all the code that locks on it is under your control (because otherwise, theoretically there could be code that you don't know about locking on the same object and causing a deadlock).

Most of the time you see dedicated lock objects exactly because of this: if you want to modify a collection that is exposed (e.g. through a property) good practice dictates that you cannot lock on the collection itself.

In this case the lock target is `private`, so if you don't explicitly expose it to the outside world you are fine.